# How to config null properties in Ms SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity:

```
public class Match
    {
        public string MatchId { get; set; }
        public int MatchNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateMatch { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TimeMatch { get; set; }
        public int MatchYear { get; set; }
        public string SeasonId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Round have value Qualified for qualify and final for Final Round
        /// </summary>
        public string Round { get; set; } 
        /// <summary>
        /// Stage have two value: Group and KnockOut
        /// </summary>        
        public string Stage { get; set; }
        public string SubStage { get; set; }
        public string HTeam { get; set; }
        public int HGoal { get; set; }
        public int GGoal { get; set; }
        public string GTeam { get; set; }
        public string WinNote { get; set; }
        public string Stadium { get; set; }
        public string Referee { get; set; }
        public long Visistors { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        #region RelationShip
        public virtual Season Seasons { get; set; }
            public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; } 
            public virtual Team GuestTeam { get; set; }
            //public Country Countries { get; set; }          
        #endregion

    }
```

And I have config it like that:

```
public class MatchesConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Match>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Match> builder)
    {            
        builder.HasKey(t => t.MatchId);
        builder.Property(t => t.DateMatch).HasColumnType("date");
        builder.Property(t => t.TimeMatch).HasColumnType("time");
        builder.Property(t => t.MatchId)
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

And it create the database table like that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv5ul.png)

For the match which is not finished, I don't have the value for HGoal and GGoal.

So How can I modify the configuration to config it.
Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to change their fields to `int?`.  The strings are probably being made Nullable because strings are objects.

Answer (score 1):

just make the properties nullable

```
public int? HGoal { get; set; }
public int? GGoal { get; set; }
```

you will have to repeat migration to database to make it working